Is there an inner product on $\mathbb{F}_p\left[S_n\right]$ for which $\langle x, x \rangle \ne 0$ for all $x$?
Let $\mathbb{F}_p\left[S_n\right]$ be the group algebra of the symmetric group $S_n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.
One can define an "inner product" in the usual way:
$$\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} x_\sigma y_\sigma$$
I am attempting to project onto the subspaces $B_i = \mathbb{F}_p\left[S_n\right]e_i$, where $1=\sum_i e_i$ are central primitive orthogonal idempotents (as in Murphy, Idempotents of the Symmetric Algebra and Nakayama's Conjecture).
Let $\{u_j\}_j$ be a basis for $B_i$. The projection would be
$$v \mapsto \sum_j \frac{\langle v,u_j\rangle}{\langle u_j,u_j\rangle}  u_j$$
however $\langle u_j,u_j\rangle = 0$ for some $u_j$. This is expected as a finite field is not ordered, and some vectors are just self-orthogonal in vector spaces over finite fields. It seems what I've defined is a symmetric bilinear form, not an inner product. Removing $\langle u_j,u_j\rangle$ from the denominator still yields a projection:
$$v \mapsto \sum_j \langle v,u_j\rangle  u_j$$
However, this isn't going to be invertible. Given the Fourier coefficients $\{\langle v, u_j\rangle\}_j$, suppose $v = u_{j^*} + v^*$ for a self-orthogonal basis vector $u_{j^*}$. Then
$$v "=" \sum_j \langle v, u_j \rangle u_j 
= \langle u_{j^*}, u_{j^*}\rangle u_{j^*} + \sum_{j \ne j^*}\langle v^*,u_j\rangle u_j
= \sum_{j \ne j^*}\langle v^*,u_j\rangle u_j
$$
So the vector $v$ loses it's $u_{j^*}$ component.
Is there an inner product on $\mathbb{F}_p\left[S_n\right]$ such that $\langle x, x \rangle \ne 0$ for all $x$?

Since, as you noted, the standard definition of inner product requires the field to be ordered, what exactly do you mean by “inner product”? Just a symmetric bilinear form, or something else?

The answer is no: if $p$ is odd, for a vector space of dimension $>2$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$, every quadratic form has a nonzero isotropic vector. (Also true and even easier for $p=2$ here.)

Chances are, whatever you have in mind is already answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6701/definition-of-inner-product-for-vector-spaces-over-arbitrary-fields .

@YCor Thank you, that answers my question. Emil, Just a symmetric bilinear form, so satisfying all properties of the inner product except positive definiteness. I mean, it's not terribly important that I use an inner product - I just want to project to the direct sum of these subspaces, which is a change of basis.

If I've understood it correctly, you're trying to find a good projection onto a block of the symmetric group in characteristic $p$. Rather than doing it via an inner product, you can just do it via multiplication by the corresponding central idempotent. This annihilates the other blocks, is the identity on your block, and is a homomorphism of algebras.

@DaveBenson Yes, you understood correctly. I think that's what I ended up doing. I just take $\text{span}_{\mathbb{F}_p}{\sigma e_i | \sigma \in S_n}$ and find a basis. Then I put the bases together (one for each block) to get a new basis for the whole algebra. Taking coordinate vectors gives the change-of-basis matrix. It sounds like what you're saying is just do $v \mapsto v e_i$ would be fine linear projection (as well as the properties you list). https://github.com/jacksonwalters/discrete-fourier-transform-over-finite-field/blob/main/symmetric_group_dft.ipynb

@JacksonWalters Yes, that's what I'm saying. Idempotents are designed for projections.

@Dave Cool, all seems to be working. Getting [36,42,42] for the dimensions of the blocks when $p=3$ and $n=5$.
